# Handling activities data with Getstream.io without having them stored in your database

Tags: php, feed, getstream-io

I have been trying Getstream.io but they don't allow you to handle the activities data freely (e.g. you are not allowed to retrieve more than a limited amount of activities at the same time, nor you can make specific queries to search for a given activity of which you don't know the ID). They mention that in the docs, recommending to: "Keep a copy of the activity stored in your own database. It makes it easier to sync updates and it allows you run custom reporting and queries on your end." By the way, I can't understand what they mean with "it makes it easier to sync updates". However, I suppose they recommend to keep your own activities database so that you can fetch the activities' IDs you need and then use them to make changes to the actual activities data on their servers.
I find it messy and I'd like to know whether or not I'm getting it right.

Answer (score 2):

I *think* that you're thinking about this the correct way.

We usually recommend that developers only store IDs / references to objects (posts/tweets, user profiles, song/playlists, whatever) in Stream for a couple reasons:

1. If you ever need to update the objects in the activity, you only need to update it in one place (your database), as opposed to in every feed that activity shows up in
2. Less bytes stored in Stream == faster fanouts, less latency for the end user

Storing IDs in Stream and then "enriching" (hydrating / deserializing) the data on read might seem a little messy, but it works pretty well at scale :)

Here's some more docs on the subject: https://getstream.io/docs/#enrichment

Hopefully this helps! Let me know if I can answer any other questions for ya.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I was not talking about actor and object's enrichment (I'm ok with that). What I am talking about is storing the whole activity record (including foreign keys to data to enrich) in my own database, plus in getstream's. That is what I find messy and I'd like to understand better.

Comment: the problem that I'm facing is, for example, how I can retrieve all of the activities that have a specific object

Comment: I'd recommend sending Stream the bare minimum: the activity's foreign id (how you identify it in your DB) and some minor other things, like actor id and maybe some fields for custom ranking... The rest should be enriched from your data store.

This way you don't need to keep Stream in sync when something trivial changes.

Comment: so do you recommend me to store activities (not enriched) both in my own DB and on getstream? isn't it too much of a messy approach?

Comment: I'd recommend storing the full, enriched activities in your own DB, and the unenriched activities in Stream. To connect the two, you'll use the `foreign_id` field on an activity - just provide a unique foreign_id every time that you create an activity. 

More docs on the `foreign_id` field here: https://getstream.io/docs/#uniqueness